# How to set default page load based on date/time in Android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing a Calendar application in Android Studio, this application contains 365 images, I want to default page load the unique page based on timestamp, for Example: if date=01.01.2022 then 1st page wants to load...

Comment: Yes, you can use the (DatePicker)[https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android]  and check the date. Compare the date then open the Activity that you want. First start the coding and let me know any issue.

Comment: material.io pages is not available ..!

Comment: I think its not shareable link, You can google material DatePicker in android

Answer (score 1):

If you want one image for each day of the year, you’ll need 366 images in leap years rather than 365.

You can test for leap year.

```
boolean isLeap = Year.now().isLeap() ;
```

If you want to load by date, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;  // Capture the current date as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

If you want to load by month and date regardless of year, use [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html).

```
 MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.now() ;
```

If you want to load by day number of year, 1-365 or 1-366, interrogate the `LocalDate` for [day of year](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfYear()).

```
int dayOfYear = today.getDayOfYear() ;
```